# Custom View Engine for SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007

Can someone suggest good high performance custom view engine / webpart for SharePoint 2007 to display large list and document libraries with paging support?  Either something that is available out in the market or open source project?

Answer (score 0):

You should read "[Scaling to Extremely Large Lists and Performant Access Methods](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2007/07/25/scaling-large-lists.aspx)" to get some key factors on efficiently retrieving list data.

As of views, you may want to perform some tests yourself to see if performance satisfactory or not.

1. Firstly, [Load your list with
   testdata](http://www.codeplex.com/sptdatapop)
2. Then create appropriate views with
   **filtering** and **sorting** and **limiting**
   in place. Show just the relevant
   results and limit the results to
   some number. Also, you may want to
   put items in folders (say, old items
   if it's suitable for your
   situation), that will provide better
   performance on querying items in
   particular container.

Comment: Thanks, I've read the whitepaper.  What I really need at the moment is a ready made solution that has this type of things implemented, probably in a 3rd party component that is plug and play ready.